# Do racial spell-like abilities need a minimun ability score to cast?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, races

Lets take Drow since they are well know. They are able to cast the spell darkness as a racial trait. Since it does not specific that any ability score is required for the casting (but might affect a dispel attempt?) none is required? Otherwise a low int fighter should be unable to cast it, or a low wis caster, or a low cha anyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drow can.
For some other races a minimum score is necessary. (the [wayangs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-wayang) for example)

Comment: Ah, so its specific to the race then. I either didnt know or had forgotten that there were some like this, thanks.

Comment: You can easily house-rule that it's the same for all classes, this is only the RAW.

Comment: Oh, the current RAW is fine, it was just a passing curiosity was all